# Achartengine how to slide faster

Tags: android, achartengine, sliding

Achartengine `LineChartView`: I need it to slide faster and more smoothly from left to right.

```
lChart = (GraphicalView) ChartFactory.getLineChartView(
                    mActivity, dataset, getRenderer(labelArrayList));
lChart.repaint();
lineLayout.addView(lChart, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: Can we see your code so far? And do you mean when you drag it?

Comment: yes，Like a Listview slide, there is inertia

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to alter the panning sensitivity. It works at the same speed as any other app on your phone that allows you to drag/pan elements of the screen.